# how to use expo-image-picker with android 11 scoped storage?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-11, react-native-permissions

I was using expo-image-picker in my expo managed react native app. It was working fine.
I just needed to use the camera to take new photo and to pick photo from gallery for my app.
For these I was using the following APIs

```
ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()
ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()

ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync()
ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync()
```

for android, my permissions array in app.json file was following

```
"permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "CAMERA_ROLL",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "LOCATION"
      ]
```

Now google sent me this email

> We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage
> flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of your app bundles or APKs.
>
> Developers with apps on devices running Android 11+ must use Scoped
> Storage to give users better access control over their device storage.
> To release your app on Android 11 or newer after May 5th, you must
> either:
>
> Update your app to use more privacy friendly best practices, such as
> the Storage Access Framework or Media Store API Update your app to
> declare the All files access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in
> the manifest file, and complete the All files access permission
> declaration in Play Console from May 5th Remove the All files access
> permission from your app entirely For apps targeting Android 11, the
> requestLegacyExternalStorage flag will be ignored. You must use the
> All files access permission to retain broad access.
>
> Apps requesting access to the All files access permission without a
> permitted use will be removed from Google Play, and you won't be able
> to publish updates.

Can anybody help me how to fix this?
Do i need to change anything in my Image picker api? Or Do i need to add / remove something from my permissions array?
Please help me ...Please...

Comment: Are you shure this image picker is causing the trouble? And then .. why do you use such an image picker if there is ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Comment: `We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file` Ok. So that would be a problem. And then we read `the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag will be ignored. ` well..  then what is the problem?

Comment: @blackapps could you please share any working snippet showing the use of ACTION_GET_CONTENT & ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT ?

Comment: You better take action yourself as the internet and also this site is full of use examples.

Comment: Oh...great..thanks...you really helped a lot... @blackapps

Comment: Well... https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12603 This is the best i got in INTERNET till now. :)

Comment: They talk there about `For SDK 40 `. Very funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.
Actually there's no problem with my code. It is google who made me confused.
Here's the detail https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12603#issuecomment-827600227